# Back button is being shown with no fragment in backstack using Navigation Component

Tags: android, android-jetpack, android-architecture-navigation

I have two fragments FragmentA and FragmentB, FragmentA is the start destination and I am going from FragmentA to FragmentB with popupTo like the following,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/main_nav_graph"
    app:startDestination="@id/fragmentA">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragmentA"
        android:name="com.example.myapplication.FragmentA"
        android:label="Emergency Application" >
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_fragmentA_to_fragmentB"
            app:destination="@id/fragmentB"
            app:popUpTo="@+id/fragmentA"
            app:popUpToInclusive="true"/>
    </fragment>
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/fragmentB"
        android:name="com.example.myapplication.FragmentB"
        android:label="Emergency Contact" />
</navigation>
```

Now, I am expecting no home button in the actionbar. My MainActivity is,

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var navController: NavController

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        navController = findNavController(R.id.main_nav_host_fragment)
        setupActionBarWithNavController(navController)
    }

    override fun onSupportNavigateUp() =
        navController.navigateUp() || super.onSupportNavigateUp()
}
```

And the outcome is

[image]

There is no fragment in the back stack and if I press the system back button, it ends. but if I press the action bar's top-left arrow, it instantiates the app. Basically, I expect no icon in the action bar as there is no fragment in the back stack.

Comment: You should never be popping the start destination of your graph, as per the [Principles of Navigation](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-principles#fixed_start_destination) as that should be the last screen the user sees before exiting your app via the system back button. Why are you doing that?

Comment: I did not know that. Thanks. I will look for an alternative solution.